# Comparar 2 array y asignar el id correspondiente de acuerdo a los valores del id_programa

Tags: javascript

comunidad, tengo dos array de objetos el cual el primero contienes los datos originales y deseo comparar si tienen el mismo id_programa_educativo el array 1 y array 2 asignar el, id correspondiente que tenía en el primer array y guardarlo en el nuevo array 3:

Array 1:

```js
const array1:[
    {id: 101, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false}
    {id: 102, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false}
    {id: 105, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
    {id: 106, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
]

const array2:[
    {id: 101, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: false}
    {id: 102, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: false}
    {id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: true}
    {id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: true}
]

//guardar nuevo array con los datos correctos (quede así)
const array3:[
    {id: 105, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: false}
    {id: 106, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: false}
    {id: 101, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: true}
    {id: 102, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: true}
]
```

Lo que tengo no es mucho pero es trabajo honesto :(

```js
var array3 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    let igual=false;
     for (let j = 0; j < array2.length & !igual; j++) {
         if(array1[i]['id_programa_educativo'] == array2[j]['id_programa_educativo']
         
              //No se como asignar el id a cada uno
     }
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y agrega tu código.

Comment: No sé cómo hacerlo empezar amigo, perdón en ese aspecto, aun ando aprendiendo, solo tengo noción de comparar los dos específicamente el id_programa_educativo y si son iguales asignar el id correspondiente, y sé que suena facil, pero no tengo de como iniciarlo :(

Comment: lee [ask], recuerda que toda pregunta debe tener una demostracion de esfuerzo y un [example]

Comment: Igual la lógica me falla mucho no se si lo estoy haciendo bien o mal :(

Comment: Seque estoy alejado a lo mejor asi no es pero asi lo he visto en otros lados pero no se como hacerlo bien bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo así:

```js
const array1 = [
  {id: 101, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false},
  {id: 102, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false},
  {id: 105, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true},
  {id: 106, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
];

const array2 = [
  {id: 101, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: false},
  {id: 102, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: false},
  {id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: true},
  {id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: true}
];

let array3 = [];
// Comenzamos por el segundo para obtener el resultado en el orden esperado
for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  let prog2 = array2[i];
  
  for (let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
    let prog1 = array1[j];
    
    // NO son el mismo
    if(prog1.id_programa_educativo !== prog2.id_programa_educativo) continue;
    
    // Actualizamos el "id"
    prog2.id = prog1.id;
    // Agregamos al array3
    array3.push(prog2);
    // Frenamos el for j
    break;
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(array3));
```

Comment: Creo que el resultado se vería mejor sin `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Y... puede ser, pero tendrías que hacer scroll para poder ver todo lo que hay en el arreglo, en cambio así, el resultado completo está visible sin tener que hacer nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias mi estimado @Marcos me ayudo mushisimo tu respuesta.

Comment: Es pregunta amigos, si en el primer array llega ver un registro más  {id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 59, activo: true} como hago para que si no encuentra un id que ponerle me lo traiga igual con el id undefined??

Comment: disculpa era en el array 2 amigo @Marcos si tienes razon el caso seria en el array 2

Comment: que me traiga igual los undefined en el array 3 aunque no tenga id se podra?

Comment: Se que te estoy pidiendo mucho amigo, pero me podrías explicar como se haría? ya es lo último que me queda por resolver

Comment: @oscarggh, sería hacer lo mismo que intentaste hacer en tu código con la variable `igual`. Al agregar el programa al `array3` le cambias el valor. Luego, después del `for`, comprobas si el valor es igual inicial y en caso afirmativo, agregas el programa al `array3`. Espero que esta vez me haya podido explicar mejor.

Comment: @Marcos esa parte si la entendí pero para implementarlo no me da la cabeza para mas. De verdad que aprecio tu ayuda amigo. No se si es mucho pedir que lo pudieras implementar en el código que hiciste arriba para tomarlo como ejemplo?

Comment: @oscarggh, te dejo [este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/xzvseb3w/), espero te sirva.

Comment: Si me super recontra sirve amigo @Marcos, de verdad agradezco mucho tu tiempo amigo. de verdad muchas gracias eres una chingoneria amigo.